# Swift 2.0 passing by value

Tags: swift, reference, deep-copy

I am just getting into structs in Swift, and I have a pretty basic question which I can't find answered elsewhere.  If you define a function which returns a new instance of a struct, how many actual objects are created?

In the example below, `CGRectMake` constructs a struct instance and returns it to this function, then the caller receives another copy.  Does this mean the following line of code would create 3 struct instances and immediately discard 2?

> **Client**:

```
var rect = makeNormalFacetTextRect();
```

> **API**:

```
class func makeNormalFacetTextRect() -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, new_width, new_height);
}
```

Furthermore, if I construct my method this way, which I often do for debugging, does that introduce yet another copy (totaling 4)?

```
class func makeNormalFacetTextRect() -> CGRect {
    var newRect = CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, new_width, new_height);

    return newRect; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html):

> Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types
>
> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a
>   variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.

In my view this means that

```
class func makeNormalFacetTextRect() -> CGRect {
    var newRect = CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, new_width, new_height);

    return newRect; 
}
```

Will create 2 structs. One will be created when `newRect` is initialised. The second one will be created when you copy `newRect` to your variable:

```
var rect = makeNormalFacetTextRect();
```

The original code is more interesting:

```
class func makeNormalFacetTextRect() -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, new_width, new_height);
}
```

When you call

```
var rect = makeNormalFacetTextRect();
```

either 1 or 2 structs will be created. I tend to believe that 1 will be created because I think Swift is optimised well enough to translate above code into:

```
var rect = CGRectMake(new_x, new_y, new_width, new_height)
```

Also, it is mentioned in the Docs that Swift optimises copying of certain value types such as Strings, Dictionaries, etc. In my view it also means that copying of Structs will be optimised as well.

In any case, both of the above codes cannot produce more than 2 structs each

Comment: I reckon that optimisation (in release version) should skip unused var `newRect` and return the value without producing addition copy.

Comment: @kostek most likely yes. However, for the debug code it also depends on what happens later. For example, if some print() is added (or some other manipulation) then it can result in 2 instances being created. Although I agree that optimisation is very good in Swift and Apple does say that we shouldn't be concerned about extra assignments of value types

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

From [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82):

> The behavior you see in your code will always be as if a copy took place. However, Swift only performs an actual copy behind the scenes when it is absolutely necessary to do so. Swift manages all value copying to ensure optimal performance, and you should not avoid assignment to try to preempt this optimization.

I think this answers your question.

Comment: That comment is specifically talking about `String`, `Array`, and `Dictionary` which have a copy on write implementation. This is _not_ true for every struct in Swift.

Comment: @Lance, I would rather say that from documentation it follows that strings, arrays and dictionaries are implemented _as structures_, and therefore behave like structures, part of which is copy on write.  Any other behaviour I would classify as a serious flaw, if not a bug, because it renders the whole  pass-by-value religion of Swift to be ineffectual.